# Most efficient way to DECODE multiple columns -- DB2

Tags: db2, decode, db2-luw

I am fairly new to DB2 (and SQL in general) and I am having trouble finding an efficient method to DECODE columns

Currently, the database has a number of tables most of which have a significant number of their columns as numbers, these numbers correspond to a table with the real values. We are talking 9,500 different values (e.g '502=yes' or '1413= Graduate Student')

In any situation, I would just do WHERE clause and show where they are equal, but since there are 20-30 columns that need to be decoded per table, I can't really do this (that I know of).

Is there a way to effectively just display the corresponding value from the other table?

Example:

```
SELECT TEST_ID, DECODE(TEST_STATUS, 5111, 'Approved, 5112, 'In Progress') TEST_STATUS
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

The above works fine.......but I manually look up the numbers and review them to build the statements. As I mentioned, some tables have 20-30 columns that would need this AND some need DECODE statements that would be 12-15 conditions.

Is there anything that would allow me to do something simpler like:

```
SELECT TEST_ID, DECODE(TEST_STATUS = *TableWithCodeValues*) TEST_STATUS
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

**EDIT:** Also, to be more clear, I know I can do a ton of INNER JOINS, but I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way than that.

Comment: Is all lookup values in one table, or is it one lookup table for every column in the query? Regardless of which I would not use DECODE for this because it will be a nightmare to maintain in the long run. Things that come to mind are if a dimension is extended with another value, 'In Progress' should be changed to something else or <drumroll> if it is decided that you must support another language.

Comment: All of the values exist in one table. So All 9,500 possible codes can be found by joining against a single table. I am not sure what you mean by 'if a dimension is extended with another value'.

Comment: If another value is added to that table you will have to change all your queries if you use decode.

Comment: Exactly why I do not want to use it. I need to prep for all future values as well. Some will only have 2-3 values and they won't change, but others will have a bunch and could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a logical point of view, I would consider splitting the lookup table into several domain/dimension tables. Not sure if that is possible to do for you, so I'll leave that part.

As mentioned in my comment I would stay away from using DECODE as described in your post. I would start by doing it as usual joins:

```
SELECT a.TEST_STATUS
     , b.TEST_STATUS_DESCRIPTION
     , a.ANOTHER_STATUS
     , c.ANOTHER_STATUS_DESCRIPTION
     , ...
FROM TEST_TABLE as a
JOIN TEST_STATUS_TABLE as b
    ON a.TEST_STATUS = b.TEST_STATUS
JOIN ANOTHER_STATUS_TABLE as c
    ON a.ANOTHER_STATUS = c.ANOTHER_STATUS
JOIN ...
```

If things are too slow there are a couple of things you can try:

- Create a statistical view that can help determine cardinalities from the joins (may help the optimizer creating a better plan):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/sl/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0021713.html

- If your license admits you can experiment with Materialized Query Tables (MQT). Note that there is a penalty for modifications of the base tables, so if you have more of a OLTP workload, this is probably not a good idea:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509melnyk/index.html

A third option if your lookup table is fairly static is to cache the lookup table in the application. Read the TEST_TABLE from the database, and lookup descriptions in the application. Further improvements may be to add triggers that invalidate the cache when lookup table is modified.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I would have to do a bunch of joins. Ah well, at least I wont have to maintain it as closely as the DECODE. Also, thankfully I do not have to worry about the performance of the tables themselves as this is a reporting db that I have full control over, but I just want to make sure that the load time of the tables stays under 90 minutes for the whole 26 of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do all these joins you could create yourself an own LOOKUP function.

```
create or replace function lookup(IN_ID INTEGER)
returns varchar(32) 
deterministic reads sql data 
begin atomic 
declare OUT_TEXT varchar(32);-- 
set OUT_TEXT=(select text from test.lookup where id=IN_ID);-- 
return OUT_TEXT;-- 
end;
```

With a table TEST.LOOKUP like

```
create table test.lookup(id integer, text varchar(32))
```

containing some id/text pairs this will return the text value corrseponding to an id .. if not found NULL.

With your mentioned 10k id/text pairs and an index on the ID field this shouldn't be a performance issue as such data amount should be easily be cached in the corresponding bufferpool.